# consuming web service with authentication allways give message Authentication required

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-2010

I try to use consume one web service with Delphi 2010.
This web service is on port 8000 with authentication.

I implement the

```
function TForm4.EncodeLoginPW(const ALogin, APW: string): string;
begin
  Result := EncdDecd.EncodeString(ALogin + ':' + APW); // EncdDecd is not documented in 
end;


procedure TForm4.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp;
  Data: Pointer);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'Authorization: Basic ' + EncodeLoginPW(UserName, Password);
  if not HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, PChar(s), Length(s), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD) then
    ShowMessage('HttpAddRequestHeaders' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));
end;
```

but I have still the message "Authentication required".

Do I make something wrong ?

Comment: Which authentication type is it? Can you successfully execute a request from a web browser with the given URL and port?

Comment: anthentication type is basic.

Comment: Can you execute a 'manual' request from a web browser to the service URL? (the browser usually will ask for authentication)

Answer (score 2):

For Basic Authentication this should work:

[Basic Authentication in Delphi 7 SOAP](http://blogs.teamb.com/deepakshenoy/2004/10/13/1584)

As explained in [this post](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/7/342246.html), newer versions of Delphi also allow to use

```
HTTPRio.HTTPWebNode.UserName := Username;
HTTPRio.HTTPWebNode.Password := Password;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it still does not work, you can try a different client (.Net or Java), and compare the HTTP traffic with the help of a local proxy ([Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Don's Proxy](http://donsproxy.moneybender.com/)) or a sniffer (WireShark), to find the relevant differences.

Comment: I have also problem with dotnet and RemoteObject SDK :(